# How to return custom JSON structure in Django Rest Framework for multiple models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, python-3.6

I am working on a project and i am stuck on registration API.Or I should override drf_multiple_models?.I am getting this response by the views that I have provided and I don't want response like this:

```
{
"message": "success",
"code": 200,
"country": [
    {
        "country_name": "nepal",
        "country_code": "977"
    }
],
"postal code": [
    {
        "post_code": 105
    }
],
"suburb": [
    {
        "suburb_name": "damak"
    }
],
"state": [
    {
        "state_name": "india1"
    }
]
}
```

but i need response like this:

```
{
"message": "success",
"code": 200,
"country": [
        {
        "country_name": "nepal",
        "country_code": "977"
        }
        "postal code":
            {
                "post_code": 105
            }
        "suburb":
            {
                "suburb_name": "damak"
            }
        "state":
            {
                "state_name": "india1"
            }
        }]
```

here is my views:

```
class InformationList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        country=self.request.query_params.get('country')
        post = self.request.query_params.get('post')
        city = self.request.query_params.get('city')
        state = self.request.query_params.get('state')

        query1 = Country.objects.filter(country_code=country).values('country_name', 'country_code')
        query2 = Post.objects.filter(post_code=post).values('post_code')
        query3 = Suburb.objects.filter(suburb_name=city).values('suburb_name')
        query4 = State.objects.filter(state_name=state).values('state_name')

        return Response({"message": "success", "code":status.HTTP_200_OK,"country": query1, "postal code": query2, "suburb": query3,
                     "state": query4})
```

need help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your queries are right, all you have to do is change the response,

```
 Response({"message": "success", "code":status.HTTP_200_OK,"country": query1[0], "postal code": query2[0], "suburb": query3[0],
                     "state": query4[0]})
```

The main reason you need to change your response is because queryset using filter creates lists of objects. If you don't want list around objects, use 'get()'

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try to keep all the data under a single variable such as:

```
dict = {}
dict['countries'] = query1, query2, query3, query4
return Response(dict)
```

and call dict as response. this might work, as of now you are calling each response independent and they appear in the given order that your output is showing